# Reading emails via graphapi and powershell

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to read the emails for my mails box via graph API with Powershell.
I got data but how to filter the data by sender.
sender                     : @{emailAddress=}
and how to get mails from specific users
$uri =  "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/$Mailbox/messages?$filter=(from/emailAddress/address) eq 'it.dsd@dadad.dasda'" - this not working
showing like this in output, but once converted to JSON I can see the sender.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you would like to filter messages that are sent  from a specific user and sent to a specific user.

AFAIK, The "To Recipient" is complex object is **NOT** filterable. Meaning you will not be able to use it with the `$filter` query parameter.

You can make use of the Search Query parameter (`$search`) to achieve your goal.

**Sample Request :**

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="to:<EMAIL ADDRESS> and from:<EMAIL ADDRESS>"`